# Filter and highlighting feature using Atlas Generation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, atlas

I have a layer containing 200 features (constituencies). There are six regions and there's a variable called REGION in my shapefile too.

I want to filter on a region (by using query builder), and highlight each constituency within that region and save the map (and get 200 maps).

How can I automate generating these 200 maps? Maybe somehow using Atlas Generation? Or a Python script?

I'm using QGIS 2.16.1 - Nodebo.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Goal: Changing highlight with semi static mapfocus

As far as i understand your task, you're trying to achieve something like this:

[image: Changing selection with semi stactic view]

I took a subset of regions in germany as example and iterated through its sub-regions while keeping the mapfocus on the region. The originally 190 maps were generated via a single atlas export procedure. *The GIF shows only a fraction of this maps because of upload limts on SE.*

---

---

### The data i'm using:

[image: Tables of used data]
[image: Basic visualization of used data]

QGIS 2.18.10 on Windows 10 (PC)

---

---

### The Workflow Summary

1. First export Regions_Layer as CSV with geometries as Well-Known-Text (WKT)
2. Join the CSV to the Sub-Regions_Layer (one to many)
3. Save the Sub-Regions_Layer as CSV without geometries
4. Add the CSV as textlayer and use the WKT column for geometries
5. Save the textlayer as shapefile for better performance
6. The Atlas_Layer has been successfully created, it includes duplicated region geometries for every sub-region feature
7. Set up the atlas
8. Set up the symbology of the Sub-Region_layer.
   **Pay extra attention to column name in the function -> it has to be written in single qotes 'column' and not with double qotes "column"**
9. After some final styling and activating the atlas preview in the composer, you're done.

---

---

### Workflow with images:

1. First export Regions_Layer as CSV with geometries as Well-Known-Text (WKT)

[image]

2. Join the CSV to the Sub-Regions_Layer (one to many)

[image]

3. Save the Sub-Regions_Layer as CSV without geometries

[image]

4. Add the CSV as textlayer and use the WKT column for geometries

[image]

5. Save the textlayer as shapefile for better performance

[image]

6. The Atlas_Layer has been successfully created, it includes duplicated region geometries for every sub-region feature.  Its table looks like this:

[image]

7. Set up the atlas

[image]
[image]

8. Set up the symbology of the Sub-Region_layer.

### **Pay extra attention to column name in the function -> it has to be written in single qotes 'column' and not with double qotes "column"**

For example, using field 'fid', you would type:
attribute($currentfeature,'fid') = attribute(@atlas_feature,'fid')

[image]

9. After some final styling and activating the atlas preview in the composer, you're done.

---

---

### Additional thoughts:

- Added a scale bar to compensate for the variable map scale
- Added an overview map for better orientation
- GIF created via GIMP 2.0